# netty maintain connections and how to notify fail to channelfuture

Tags: java, netty

I am try to create a while loop in client that trying to maintain a number of connections to server.
When a channel handler got certain response (error) from server, it should close the channel and mark this channel future failed.

```
Channel channel = this.channelPool.acquire().syncUninterruptibly().getNow();
// release channel when closed to unblock creating new channel.
channel.closeFuture().addListener((ChannelFutureListener) future -> {
    // not success wait and retry
    if(!future.isSuccess()){
         trySleep();
    }
    // close normally, no error, release so can create another connection immediately
    this.channelPool.release(future.channel());
});
```

There are two questions here

1. is it the proper way to use while loop and FixedChannelPool to maintain number of connections from client to server?
2. How to make the channelFuture fail? CloseFuture class always set success when setClosed() is called
   https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/AbstractChannel.java#L1159

this example is a good way to keep one connection. but it requires singleton which is I want to avoid.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out just to use ChannelAttribute to pass info.

```
ctx.channel().attr(OneAttribute).set(true);
ctx.close();
```

then

```
channel.closeFuture().addListener((ChannelFutureListener) future -> {
// not success wait and retry
if(future.channel().attr(OneAttribute) == some value){
     trySleep();
}
// close normally, no error, release so can create another connection immediately
this.channelPool.release(future.channel());
```